# How to show values from a generated column (containing a complex formula) in PostgreSQL with date_trunc?

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to DB. Here's the scenario

Table x

```
id(serial)    Col1(date/ts)     Col2(numeric)   Col3(numeric)    Col4-Generated(numeric) 
auto          Date of record    val1            val2             Preset formula using val1 & val2
```

how do I do

```
select date_trunc('month',sum(Col1)), sum(Col2), sum(Col3), Col4 Preset formula ....
```

without using any aggregate function for Col4 or writing the actual formula?

Comment: `date_trunc('month',sum(Col1))`  makes no sense. You can't "sum" a date - what is the sum of yesterday, today and the day after tomorrow?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260703

Comment: Sorry a mistake. I meant date_trunc('month', Col1) . On the second link you provided, its promising but in my example Col4 is a generated column (stored) with some formula on Col2 and Col3 so has values.

Comment: @PurbaragJena . . . The SQL query does not know what formula is used to generate `col4`.  It only knows what the values are.  You have to provide some expression to get the aggregation you want.